# Integrating Step Function and SQS with EventBridge Pipes Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge, aws-sqs-fifo

I need to integrate a SQS with my Step Function using EventBridge Pipes. The Pipe is composed of SQS fifo queue (Source) and Step Function (Target). Below is the Step Function definition:

```
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Pass",
  "States": {
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "List Executions",
      "Parameters": {
        "messageId.$": "$.[0].messageId",
        "receiptHandle.$": "$.[0].receiptHandle",
        "body.$": "$.[0].body",
        "attributes.$": "$.[0].attributes"
      }
    },
    "List Executions": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn.$": "$$.StateMachine.Id",
        "StatusFilter": "RUNNING"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:listExecutions",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "StateMachineArn.$": "$$.StateMachine.Id",
        "uuid.$": "States.UUID()",
        "runningExecutionsCount.$": "States.ArrayLength($.Executions)"
      },
      "Next": "Receive Message",
      "ResultPath": "$.ExecutionDetails"
    },
    "Receive Message": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Process Finished",
      "Parameters": {
        "MaxNumberOfMessages": 1,
        "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/test-sqs.fifo"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "body.$": "States.StringToJson($.Messages[0].Body)",
        "ReceiptHandle.$": "$.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle"
      }
    },
    "Process Finished": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

This Step Function is failed each time a simple message like `{"message": "Hi there!"}` is sent from SQS:

Exception:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'ReceiveMessage' (entered at the event id #9). The function 'States.StringToJson($.Messages[0].Body)' had the following error: The JsonPath argument for the field '$.Messages[0].Body' could not be found in the input '{}'
```

It seems that the input message is sort of ignored.

Comment: What input are providing to the step function execution?

Comment: @ThomasBoudreau The input to the step function is the SQS message: ```{"message": "Hi there!"}```

Comment: What's the content of the message that the workflow gets in the `Receive Message` state?

Comment: @ThomasBoudreau, I'm new to SQS. I have a payload which is sent from SQS fifo to step function to be processed. This payload is something like ```{"id": 123, "price": 100,...}```.  I wanted top test "List Executions" first and that is why I tried ```{"message": "Hi there!"}```. In order to test it, I entered ```{"message": "Hi there!"}``` as message body to send it to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the error is caused by the fact that you are using SQS to trigger your State Machine and then trying to fetch another message from the same queue (in your `Receive Message` state) that has no more messages in it.

If you remove the `ResultSelector` from the `Receive Message` state you'll see the output is

```
{
  "Messages": []
}
```

which does not contain anything since the message you sent has already been consumed by triggering your State Machine (which should now succeed).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBoudreau, then what is the proper approach for the Pipe to poll SQS queue and initiate the step function execution per message received?

Comment: You actually already have that setup correctly, you just don't need the `Receive Message` state. If you send a message to the queue and look at the Execution Input for the latest execution of your state machine, you'll see the body of the message is present.